# R: trouble with mle() error: non-finite finite-difference value [2]

Tags: r, statistics, estimation, mle

I have a simple `x, y` data.frame.

```
mydata <- data.frame(days = 1:96, risk = c(5e-09, 5e-09, 5e-09, 1e-08, 4e-08, 6e-08, 9e-08, 1.5e-07, 4.2e-07, 
                                           7.2e-07, 1.02e-06, 1.32e-06, 1.66e-06, 2.19e-06, 2.76e-06, 3.32e-06, 
                                           3.89e-06, 4.55e-06, 5.8e-06, 7.16e-06, 8.51e-06, 9.85e-06, 1.138e-05, 
                                           1.396e-05, 1.672e-05, 1.947e-05, 2.222e-05, 2.521e-05, 2.968e-05, 
                                           3.439e-05, 3.909e-05, 4.378e-05, 4.894e-05, 5.697e-05, 6.546e-05, 
                                           7.392e-05, 8.236e-05, 9.16e-05, 0.00010573, 0.00012063, 0.00013547, 
                                           0.00015025, 0.00016642, 0.00019127, 0.00021743, 0.00024343, 0.00026924, 
                                           0.00029818, 0.00034681, 0.00039832, 0.00044932, 0.00049976, 0.0005451, 
                                           0.00056293, 0.00057586, 0.00058838, 0.0006005, 0.00061562, 0.00065079, 
                                           0.00068845, 0.00072508, 0.00076062, 0.00079763, 0.00084886, 0.00090081, 
                                           0.0009507, 0.00099844, 0.00104427, 0.00108948, 0.00113175, 0.00117056, 
                                           0.00120576, 0.00123701, 0.00126253, 0.00128269, 0.00129757, 0.00130716, 
                                           0.00131291, 0.00132079, 0.0013216, 0.00131392, 0.00129806, 0.00127247, 
                                           0.00122689, 0.00117065, 0.00110696, 0.00103735, 0.00095951, 0.00085668, 
                                           0.0007517, 0.00065083, 0.000556, 0.0004669, 0.00037675, 0.00029625, 
                                           0.00093289))
```

I think `Weibull(3, 0.155)` is a pretty good fit to my data, judging from the plot below.

```
plot(1:96, dweibull(mydata$risk, shape = 3, scale = 0.155), type = "l", xlab = "days", ylab = "risk")
lines(mydata, type = "l", col = "grey")
legend("topleft", c("Data", "Estimate"), col = c("black", "grey"), lty = c(1, 1))
```

[image]

I write a function that calculates the negative log-likelihood, which will be passed into `mle`.

```
estimate <- function(kappa, lambda){
  -sum(dweibull(mydata$y, shape = kappa, scale = lambda, log = TRUE))
}
```

I call `mle`, provide my initial parameter estimates, and obtain the following error.

```
> mle(estimate, start = list(kappa = 3, lambda = 0.155))
Error in optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, ...) : 
  non-finite finite-difference value [2]
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

What went wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you want to do?  From what I can tell, you have a dataset of 96 values of "risk", and you want to fit it's distribution with weibull.  Note that "days" is not relevant at all if this is the case.  You have an unordered vector of values.

The figure above is misleading.  You calculate `dweibull()` for risk values.  The figure indicates that `dweibull(risk)` is roughly equal to risk.  This is a rather different claim than weibull with given parameters being a good fit.

for instance, here is the distribution of your data:
`hist(mydata$risk, breaks=15)`
[image]
while the weibull density with your parameters in the relevant range looks like this: `curve((function(x) dweibull(x, shape=3, scale=0.155))(x), 0, 0.0014)`
[image]

Hence these distributions are very different.  I would say your empirical distributions is uniform plus mass at zero, not weibull.

Now to your last problem: as the distributions do not fit well, the optimizer runs into numerical singularities.  I don't know `mle()` too well, but with a little tweaks `maxLik::maxLik()` will show the problem:

```
estimate <- function(par){
   Kappa <- par[1]
   Lambda <- par[2]
   dweibull(mydata$risk, shape = Kappa, scale = Lambda, log = TRUE)
}
summary(maxLik::maxLik(estimate, start=c(Kappa=3, Lambda=0.155), method="BHHH"))
```

gives you

```
--------------------------------------------
Maximum Likelihood estimation
BHHH maximisation, 43 iterations
Return code 2: successive function values within tolerance limit
Log-Likelihood: 682.743 
2  free parameters
Estimates:
        Estimate Std. error t value Pr(> t)    
Kappa  0.4849129  0.0473720  10.236 < 2e-16 ***
Lambda 0.0002953  0.0001028   2.873 0.00407 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
--------------------------------------------
```

Note that I did one major change: removing `sum` from your log-likelihood, and using BHHH optimizer.  This typically more stable than optimizing based on a single summed likelihood.  You should also seriously consider writing analytic derivatives for the estimation.

You can check that the distributions look a lot more similar now.

Comment: Thank you. Regarding your last comment, how can I check that the distributions look a lot more similar now? I tried `plot(dweibull(1:95, shape = 0.4838894, scale = 0.0002961))` but it looks different from the distribution of my data?

Comment: You can start with something simple like qqplot.  You can also see how similar are the moments and other characteristics of these two distributions.  And finally, you can calculate some sort of distance between these two distributions--for instance, Kulback-Leibler distance (which is the same as log-likelihood).  The latter will also work for certain tests.

Comment: Is there a quick graphical way to see if the two distributions are similar? Along the lines of plotting the densities.

Comment: `fitdistrplus::plotdist(risk, "weibull", list(shape=0.4838894, scale=0.0002961))` is doing quite a good job in my opinion.  (`risk` is your risk variable).

Comment: Thank you. I would like to clarify that `mydata` actually contains densities (I do not have the raw data), so I think my first plot (where I compared weibull densities to `mydata$risk`) shows a good fit. In your response we're technically looking at the densities of `mydata$risk`, i.e. densities of densities...correct?

Comment: Yes.  I assumed `mydata` contains your random variables, not densities...

Comment: That's why I'm confused as to why plotting `plot(dweibull(1:95, shape = 0.4838894, scale = 0.0002961))` looks very different from `lines(mydata$risk, col = "grey)`

Comment: I see. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Indeed, sorry for that.  Here you may consider using NLLS for estimation.